# Is every weak sequence in a separable Hilbert space, a strong sequence?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, separable-spaces, strong-convergence

I'm concluding something that is not convincing me.

Imagine a sequence of elements $x_k$ in an Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, then if it is weakly convergent to $x$ that means
$$
\lim_{k\to +\infty} 
\langle x_k - x, y\rangle = 0
\,\forall y\in\mathcal{H}
$$
In particular this holds for all the elements $y=e_j\in\mathcal{H}$ where $\{e_j\}$ constitutes a complete orthonormal sequence in a separable Hilbert space, so we have
$$
\lim_{k\to +\infty} 
\langle x_k - x, e_j\rangle
=
\left\langle \lim_{k\to +\infty} x_k - x, e_j\right\rangle
=
0
\,\forall j
$$
but Hilbert space is indeed separable so we have
$$
\lim_{k\to +\infty} x_k - x
=
\sum\limits_j
\left\langle \lim_{k\to +\infty} x_k - x, e_j\right\rangle
e_j
=
0
$$
(see for example "Hilbert spaces with applications - Debnath, Mikusinski" third edition pag. 115 theorem 3.4.14) and this means
$$
\left\lVert \lim_{k\to +\infty} x_k - x\right\rVert
=
\lim_{k\to +\infty} \lVert x_k - x\rVert
=
0
$$
so the sequence $\{x_k\}$ is strongly convergent to its weak limit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using the expression $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k-x$ as though it had a meaning, but your assumptions don't guarantee that.

Comment: Ok, so in other words I can define by force a quantity like $\lim_{k\to +\infty}(x_k-x)$ on itself, only if it is strongly convergent? Norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, but I can call it $A$, is a continuos application and that means $\lim_{k\to +\infty} A(X_k)=A(\lim_{k\to +\infty} X_k)$ where $\lim_{k\to +\infty}X_k$ is determined, by definition of continuity, by strong convergence. So in this case $X_k= x_k - x$ and defining $\lim_{k\to +\infty} x_k - x\doteq 0$ we get by continuity of the norm $\lim_{k\to +\infty}\lVert x_k-x\Vert=\lVert\lim_{k\to +\infty}x_k-x\rVert=0$, so the definition works

Comment: But scalar product is a continuos application with the induced norm, so if I fix $y$ and I call $\langle x, y\rangle\doteq A x$ I can say $A$ is a continuos application and I can "enter the limit" defined above, only if the sequence converges strongly first. Is my interpretation right? Am I brute-forcing too much, or becoming tautological?

Comment: You cannot pull the limit in the inner product. Because the limit of $x_k$ might not exists. Test your argument for the standard non-strongly but weakly converging sequence: $(e_k)$ an orthonormal sequence.

Comment: @daw Exactly I was just thinking to that!